# Display data from database using <optgroup> and <option> tags

Tags: php, html, database

The main goal I try to get is, the correct display data from the database, let me try to explain with the code.

This is my form code for now:

```
<form action="" id="omnivaform" onsubmit="nextStep();" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="choose_omniva" />
        <div id="OmnivaSelector">
            <?php
            $omniva_variants_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `omniva` ORDER BY `region` ASC;');
            $omniva_variants_query->execute();
            if( $omniva_variants_query->fetchColumn() == 1)
            {
                $omniva_variants_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `omniva`ORDER BY `region` ASC;');
                $omniva_variants_query->execute();
                
                $omniva_variant_record = $omniva_variants_query->fetch();
                ?>
                <select id="omniva_selector" name="omniva_variant" style="display:none">
                    <option value="<?php echo $omniva_variant_record["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $omniva_variant_record["region"]; ?></option>
                </select>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                $omniva_variants_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `omniva` ORDER BY `region` ASC;');
                $omniva_variants_query->execute();
                ?>
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Choose your Omniva</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <select id="omniva_variant_selector" class="form-control" />
                            <?php
                            while( $omniva_variant_record = $omniva_variants_query->fetch() )
                            {
                                ?>
<optgroup label="<?php echo $omniva_variant_record["region"]; ?>">
<option><?php echo $omniva_variant_record["name"]; ?></option>
                                                            </optgroup>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        </script>
    </form>
```

and the result that I get from this code is a dropdown selection which looks like this

```
Region 1
  address 1

Region 1
  address 2

Region 2
  address 1

Region 3
  address 1
```

But I need that this dropdown looks like this:

```
Region 1
  address 1
  address 2

Region 2
  address 1

Region 3
  address 1
  address 2
  address 3

Region 4
  address 1
```

If a region has more than one address, then these address show under these regions

Please don't judge the code, I know this is not perfect, but everything is working, except the dropdown

Here are two images that explain how it's now and how it should be

[First image how it's for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP0CW.png)
[Second image, how it's should be looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiXqB.png)

Thank you everyone for helping me!HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <optgroup label="<?php echo $omniva_variant_record["region"]; ?>">
 <?php while( $omniva_variant_record = $omniva_variants_query->fetchAll() ): ?>     
     <option><?php echo $omniva_variant_record["name"]; ?></option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </optgroup>
```

You need to use `fetchAll()` istead of `fetch()`. `fetchAll()` returns the values as an associative array.

Note that `fetchAll()` works only when `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` is set to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` without which you need to supply `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as argument to `fetchAll()`.

Also note that I have used the alternative syntax for the while loop. You are free to use any syntax but this alternate syntax makes the code much easier to read.

#### Quoting from PHP Manual

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.

For more information visit [PHP: Alternative syntax for control structures - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

*Edit:*

You can try this

```
<?php
    $outgroup = $db_link->prepare("SELECT region FROM `omniva` GROUP BY `region`;");
    $outgroup->execute();
    while ($outgroup_record = $outgroup->fetch()):
?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo $outgroup_record["region"]; ?>">
            <?php   
            $address_options = $db_link->prepare("SELECT name FROM `omniva` WHERE region=:region GROUP BY name;");
            $address_options->bindParam('region', $outgroup_record['region']);
            $address_options->execute();
            while ($address_options_records = $address_options->fetch()): ?>    
            <option><?php echo $address_options_records["name"]; ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </optgroup>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This will first fetch the unique `region`s and then for each row returned it will fetch the `name` whose `region` matches the value of `$outgroup_record['region']`. Then proceed to output the result in a `<option>` tag. Modify the queries as per your need.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer @ghoshriju33 as I mentioned on other answer, I get only addresses without regions and fetchAll() not working as well. When I use fetchAll(), then I get nothing, but with fetch() I get just addresses

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump` of `$omniva_variants_query->fetch()` and `$omniva_variants_query->fetchAll()` ? @EdijsMaļinovskis

Comment: @ghoshriju32 When I use `$omniva_variants_query->fetch()`  I get `bool (false)` but when I use `$omniva_variants_query->fetchAll()`  I get  `array (0) {}`

Comment: @EdijsMaļinovskis try using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and see if it works

Comment: unfortunately, no change. With `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` no region and no address. With `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` no region, but have all addresses

Comment: Is `var_dump` returning `array(0)` after using  `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`? @EdijsMaļinovskis

Comment: @ghoshriju32 yes, it's returning `array (0) {}` after using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Pretty much weird. I found a typo error in the SQL statement ```$omniva_variants_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `omniva`ORDER BY `region` ASC;');```. There's no space between ``omniva`` and `ORDER`. And can you post the structure of the database columns? @EdijsMaļinovskis

Comment: Are the SQL queries working fine? How about using ```"SELECT * FROM omniva ORDER BY region ASC;"``` instead of ```'SELECT * FROM `omniva` ORDER BY `region` ASC;'``` ? @EdijsMaļinovskis

Comment: Please check the link https://github.com/edijsmalinovskis/Stackoverflow/  here is full code and some images

Comment: @EdijsMaļinovskis your database tables are setup incorrectly. You need to setup a parent-child relationship. Best would be to establish one-to-many relationship between `region` and `name`. Then fetch the `region`s, iterate over them and fetch the `name`

Comment: @EdijsMaļinovskis I updated my answer. Let me know if the code works.

Comment: thank you. you helped resolve the problem. Thank you for your helping and your time

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" id="omnivaform" onsubmit="nextStep();" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="choose_omniva" />
    <div id="OmnivaSelector">
        <?php
        $omniva_variants_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `omniva` ORDER BY `region` ASC;');
        $omniva_variants_query->execute();
        if ($omniva_variants_query->fetchColumn() == 1) {
            $omniva_variants_query = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `omniva`ORDER BY `region` ASC;');
            $omniva_variants_query->execute();

            $omniva_variant_record = $omniva_variants_query->fetch();
        ?>
            <select id="omniva_selector" name="omniva_variant" style="display:none">
                <option value="<?php echo $omniva_variant_record["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $omniva_variant_record["region"]; ?></option>
            </select>
        <?php
        } else { ?>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Choose your Omniva</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="omniva_variant_selector" class="form-control" />
                        <?php
                         $outgroup = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `omniva` ORDER BY `region` ASC;');
                         $outgroup->execute();
                        while ($outgroup_record = $outgroup->fetch()) {
                        ?>
                            <optgroup label="<?php echo $outgroup_record["region"]; ?>">
                            <?php   
                            $address_options = $db_link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `omniva` ORDER BY `address` ASC;');
                            $address_options->execute();
                                while ($address_options_records = $address_options->fetch()) { ?>

                                <option><?php echo $address_options_records["name"]; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </optgroup>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: You just need to move the optgroup from the loop so it will not repeat simple

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer @Shakeel Ahmad but when I move optgroup to outside while loop, then I get just all addresses without region, only <option> work and that's it

Comment: Okey then in that case you need to change your logic fully, you need main query to get the optgroup and then in loop add other query which will search for the option and print the options

Comment: Please check the answer, I change your query little bit please modify according to you need, I just give you the idea, Hopefully this will work